# User Input on a 2D Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, position, user-input

I am trying to implement the knights tour problem on a 3x4 grid display. My grid is displayed as follows:

```
   A B C D
1: 1 - - -
2: - - - -
3: - - - -
```

The user starts on A1, which is [0][0] on the 2D array. How would I associate my user input with other positions on the grid. For example, if the user was to type A2 (I'm aware this isn't a valid knight move) - how would I let the program know this is position [0][1] on the array (I think)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: split it.A and 2.then A is 0 and 2 is 2-1=1

Comment: Any idea how I could implement this in code? The letters A B C D are a char called 'file' and my number 1, 2 and 3 are an int called 'rank'.

Comment: you can use if else ,switch case to check a or b or ..etc. you can do it also using character code but if else should be fine.and can you share the codes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have index `i, j` for `2DArray[i][j]`: then you can use 
`i = rank - 1`, and `j = file - 65` exploiting char autocasting to int and ASCII int values to obtain the correct 2D array position.